# Some basic HTML5 questions regarding validation and semantic tags

Tags: javascript, html

## 1

`<div id="header"></div>`

can be replaced by

`<header></header>`

in HTML5. But besides better readability, are there any other reasons to use this?

## 2

```
<input type="text"   
   name="username"   
   id="username"  
   placeholder="4 <> 10"  
   pattern="[A-Za-z]{4,10}"  
   autofocus  
   required>
```

This will cause some validation when placed inside a form. Is there any way to inspect what kind of javascript that is beeing generated? Can you modify it?

Thanks

Comment: Native validation isn't JavaScript...

Comment: If you have two questions that are completely unrelated (beyond them being about features introduced in the same (very large spec) please ask two separate questions and not one question with two parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, it is more semantically correct. The search engines are already interpreting the HTML5 tags according to their semantics. So, improving the SEO.

2) Something like that. You can use [`setCustomValidity`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#dom-cva-setcustomvalidity) to change message:

```
 function check(input) {
   if (input.value == "good") {
     input.setCustomValidity('"' + input.value + '" is not a feeling.');
   } else {
     input.setCustomValidity('');
   }
 }
```